# JIRA test case execution using SoapUI

Tags: groovy, jira, soapui, jira-rest-api

I want that whenever my SoapUI testsuite run, it should add soapui testcase (I have stored JIRA_ID in custom property) to JIRA testcycle and execute the testcase. It would be great if it's first create testcycle and then add testcases to it.

Is this possible without using ZAPI?

I am not able to find the open restful JIRA api.

Need an idea from where i can start this.

Comment: I believe that there is _REST API_ to interact with `JIRA` available. See https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/

Comment: Yes, I saw their api documentation before, but I only found Get API for status. There is no api for set the status of Issue.

Comment: How about this - https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-do-I-retrieve-issues-of-specific-status-with-JQL/qaq-p/540468

Comment: This is for search issue in JIRA.

Comment: The first link allows to create and 2nd one for search. Then what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have to change testcase status not create new testcase. For this i need to search testcase first. For that second link is useful. but the second step is changing status (Which i am looking for).

Comment: There is no way to achieve this without ZAPI. Get source code using ZAPI - > https://github.com/rajnegi/JIRA